# Which George V stamp would be used for a letter sent from London to Sweden in 1919/1920?

Tags: 20th-century

I've inherited some letters that my great-grandmother sent from London, UK to Stockholm, Sweden in 1919 and 1920. Unfortunately the stamps have been cut out (probably by a relative who wished to save them somewhere else). My question is therefore: Do you know which George V stamp could have been used? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5):

Depends on the [exact weight](http://www.gbps.org.uk/information/rates/overseas/surface/letters-1875-1975.php) - a half-ounce letter would be 2 1/2d, a one-ounce letter 4d. ([Postcards](http://www.gbps.org.uk/information/rates/overseas/surface/postcards.php) were 1d until 1921).

There were [standard definitive stamps](http://www.stamp-exchange.co.uk/catalogue/king_george_v_1912-1924.htm) for 2 1/2d and 4d (blue and grey respectively) so it is likely these would have been used, but a combination of smaller ones might have been used if they were to hand.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! The square that was cut out of the envelope is so small that it must have been a single stamp. And it was only a few pages, so I'm guessing it was 2 1/2d. Or could it be 2d orange?

Comment: It would only have been 2d to "Empire" destinations, I think - so probably 2 1/2 d.